# How to add a field in JSON structure automatically

Tags: json, python-3.x, google-bigquery, terraform

I am using bigquery and getting the Schema details using the below command

```
bq show --schema --format=prettyjson [PROJECT_ID]:[DATASET].[TABLE]
```

The above command gives me something like the below structure

```
[
  {
    "mode": "NULLABLE",
    "name": "flt_date",
    "type": "DATE"
  },
  {
    "mode": "NULLABLE",
    "name": "month",
    "type": "INTEGER"
  },
  {
    "mode": "NULLABLE",
    "name": "year",
    "type": "INTEGER"
  },
]
```

I would like to add an extra field called "description" in each array structure, Can anyone please help me with how to get this.Any script or any command would be helpful. The new structure would be

```
[
  { "description" : " ",
    "mode": "NULLABLE",
    "name": "flt_date",
    "type": "DATE"
  },
  { "description" : " ",
    "mode": "NULLABLE",
    "name": "month",
    "type": "INTEGER"
  },
  { "description" : " ",
    "mode": "NULLABLE",
    "name": "year",
    "type": "INTEGER"
  },
]
```

**Note:** My existing table doesn't have any description for column Names which I need to add later using terraform. Any Suggestions would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Iterate through each and use `.update()`

```
json = [
  {
    "mode": "NULLABLE",
    "name": "flt_date",
    "type": "DATE"
  },
  {
    "mode": "NULLABLE",
    "name": "month",
    "type": "INTEGER"
  },
  {
    "mode": "NULLABLE",
    "name": "year",
    "type": "INTEGER"
  },
]

for each in json:
    each.update({"description":" "})
```

Comment: While making the changes, I encountered two-issue - "Expected a JSON object, array or literal.json" Although, I have fixed the First one and modified the same 

{
  "json" :  [
  {
    "mode": "NULLABLE",
    "name": "flt_date",
    "type": "DATE"
  },
  {
    "mode": "NULLABLE",
    "name": "month",
    "type": "INTEGER"
  },
  {
    "mode": "NULLABLE",
    "name": "year",
    "type": "INTEGER"
  }
]
}

for each in json:
    each.update({"description":" "})
But this started giving me a second Error - "end of file expected JSON"
May I know how to resolve this?

Comment: can you share the full code thats causing this?

Comment: May I know where I should run this ? Any online website where I can use this?